# Что нужно для обработки анимаций через imagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick

Есть нативный пример с imagick:

```
   <?
    $gif = new Imagick('test.gif');

    foreach ($gif as $frame) {
        $frame->thumbnailImage(50, 50);
        $frame->setImagePage(50, 50, 0, 0);     
    }

    $gif->writeImages("example_small.gif", true);
    ?>
```

Сам imagick 3.0.0RC1

Есть поддержка GIF, GIF87

Но почему то этот скрипт очень долго обрабатывает 7 кадровую анимацию, весом 135 кб.

В основном происходит вылет таймаута, а сам скрипт отбирает все память у серва (400мб).

Действительно ли imagick такой прожорливый или просто стоит неправильная настройка сервера?

Comment: Не в тему вопроса. Сам вожусь сейчас с генерируемой php gif-анимацией, остановился на GD. Если не секрет, над чем работаете, и не собираетесь ли реализовывать нетривиальные motion-graphics эффекты в итоге? Композитинг, маски, motion blur.

Comment: Да нет, как раз таки мне необходим обычный ресайз, установка текста на кадр, а так же накладывание самого кадра на обработанный слой. Хотелось бы это конечно реализовать через gd, но решил попробовать через imagick.
Через gd, я так понял, это получение кода гифки и его разбивания на кадры через регепс? А потом как с обычным изображением, поциклово обрабатывая и собирая кадры воедино?